# Nginx works as a reverse proxy but doesn't pass traffic to Puma via a socket

Tags: sockets, nginx, reverse-proxy, puma

I have a web application fronted by Nginx as the web server. When it is configured as below, it works. Hitting http://192.168.33.10:9174/ yields a "402 Payment Required"

```
# /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapp

server {
  listen  9174;
  server_name 127.0.0.1;
  location /status {
    stub_status on;
    access_log off;
  }
  return 402;
}
```

It works.

I then tried to get it to forward traffic to a Puma application server, but it failed. I then set up a bunch of proxies as follows:

```
# /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapp
upstream sqlitething {
  server www.sqlite.org;
}

upstream hwacithing {
  server www.hwaci.com;
}

upstream appthing {
  #server unix:///home/deployer/myapp/shared/sockets/socktest.sock 
  server unix:/home/deployer/myapp/shared/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen   80;
  server_name 192.168.33.10;
  location / {
     proxy_pass http://sqlitething;
  }
}

server {
  listen   8080;
  server_name 192.168.33.10;
  location / {
     proxy_pass http://hwacithing;
  }
}

server {
  listen   8099;
  server_name 192.168.33.10;
  location / {
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
     proxy_redirect off;
     proxy_pass http://appthing;
  }
}

server {
  listen  9175;
  server_name 192.168.33.10;
  return 402;
}
```

Here are my results when I hit the URL with a browser:

- http://192.168.33.10:80, it proxied  www.sqlite.org (as expected).
- http://192.168.33.10:8080, it proxied www.hwaci.com (as expected)
- http://192.168.33.10:9175, returned a HTTP 402 (Payment Required) message (as expected)
- http://192.168.33.10:8099 tried to redirect me to https://appthing, but nothing happened (NOT EXPECTED)

The socket file exists with the permissions as follow:

```
srwxrwxrwx 1 deployer deployer 0 Jun  8 19:15 /home/deployer/myapp/shared/sockets/puma.sock
```

-------- UPDATE June 8 5:57 EST --------------------

I tried the following for the failed URL:

```
$ curl -isL http://192.168.33.10:8099
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.1.19
Date: Wed, 08 Jun 2016 21:52:54 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://appthing/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

I tried the following for the successful URL

```
$ curl -isL http://192.168.33.10:8080
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.1.19
Date: Wed, 08 Jun 2016 21:54:46 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 1167
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Host
Last-Modified: Wed, 13 Dec 2006 14:54:32 GMT
ETag: "88047-48f-4247d938f5a00"
Accept-Ranges: bytes

<html><head><title>Hwaci Homepage</title></head><body bgcolor="white">
    <font size="7"><b>Hwaci</b></font><br>



...etc...
```

---

-----   UPDATE June 9 11:24 AM EST  --------------

I added in the lines

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_redirect off;
```

to the server/listen block for port 8099 which connected to the Unix socket. I got the same result.

I then went to http://blog.honeybadger.io/how-unicorn-talks-to-nginx-an-introduction-to-unix-sockets-in-ruby/ and set up a little socket server as they specified but with the socket at

```
unix:///home/deployer/myapp/shared/sockets/socktest.sock
```

I then modified the nginx.conf so that it wouldn't daemonize and that errors would go to the stdout.

```
daemon off;
error_log /dev/stdout info;
```

I then ran nginx as

```
> sudo nginx -c nginx.conf
```

When I ran curl to hit the nginx/socket combo, I got this:

```
$ curl -isL http://192.168.33.10:8099
HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
Server: nginx/1.1.19
Date: Thu, 09 Jun 2016 15:13:57 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 173
Connection: keep-alive

<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.1.19</center>
</body>
</html>
```

The nginx logs looked like this:

```
2016/06/09 15:13:34 [notice] 9885#0: start worker process 9889
2016/06/09 15:13:49 [info] 9886#0: *1 client 192.168.33.1 closed keepalive connection
2016/06/09 15:13:57 [crit] 9886#0: *3 connect() to unix:/home/deployer/myapp/shared/sockets/socktest.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.33.1, server: 192.168.33.10, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/deployer/myapp/shared/sockets/socktest.sock:/", host: "192.168.33.10:8099"
2016/06/09 15:13:57 [info] 9886#0: *3 client 192.168.33.1 closed keepalive connection
```

----- end June 9 update ------------------- - - - - - - - ---

The Puma processes are running

```
deployer@host0:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled$ ps -ef | grep puma
deployer 21319     1  0 19:15 ?        00:00:00 puma 2.16.0 (unix:///home/deployer/myapp/shared/sockets/puma.sock) [20160608191112]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
deployer 21322 21319  0 19:15 ?        00:00:09 puma: cluster worker 0: 21319 [20160608191112]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
deployer 21326 21319  0 19:15 ?        00:00:10 puma: cluster worker 1: 21319 [20160608191112]
```

I am configuring the upstream to Puma as specified in various configuration guides. What am I doing wrong?

Is there a way to see if the Puma process is actually serving my web app?

Is there a way to access the Puma process using curl or wget and via the Unix socket (unix:/home/deployer/myapp/shared/sockets/puma.sock)?

Comment: What do you mean by "tried to redirect, but nothing happened"? What happens exactly, when you hit the `http://192.168.33.10:8099/` url?

Comment: The web browser redirects me to https://appthing.

Comment: You mean, literally to `https://appthing/`?

Comment: That's what it says in the browser window.

Comment: $ curl 192.168.33.10:8099
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0

I got nothing with curl.

Comment: Try searching for `appthing` everywhere inside `/etc/nginx/`, somewhere there is a permanent redirect. And make sure you don't have `appthing` in `/etc/hosts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, I got the socket server working by doing a

```
> chmod 777 /home/deployer/myapp/shared/sockets/socktest.sock
```

That told me that my Nginx setup was good.

But the Puma socket kept failing.

It turned out that the web application behind the Puma application server was configured:

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

Once I realized that, I configured Nginx to listen on port 443, turned on SSL, set up some self-signed certificates, and ......... it worked.

The lesson in all of this was that my knowledge of Nginx, Puma, sockets, permissions, and SSL were all weak at the same time, and that is why I couldn't figure out what was going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your puma app is attempting to upgrade the connection from http to https. It does this by issuing a redirect. To remain a portable app, it is using the HOST field in the request header to determine its name.

In your location block you do not specify any `proxy_set_header` directives and therefore `nginx` has inserted default values for HOST and CONNECTION. The value for HOST being "appthing".

You probably need to set some `proxy_set_header` directives of your own to let the app know its true name, possibly convince the app that the connection is already secure and maybe set some `proxy_redirect` directives to map bogus redirects to an acceptable value.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header) for details.